# Can I call a function in both create and update in ModelSerializer

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

### Can i call same function in both create and update without overriding it?

Hi im fairly new at this and trying to implement my code using the **DRY** **principle**.
So im calling a function say for ***create_update_password*** in **ModelSerializer's** while creating or changing the password for this i have to **override create and update** in **ModelSerializer** and ***create_update_password*** in both of them. Im not doing any extra functionality in any of them them apart from calling this function. So is there any way that i can invoke this function in create and update without overrding it.
Ill really appericiate it if anyone can give any suggestion. Below is the code Example
Thanks You

```
    def create_update_password(self, instance, validated_data):
        password = validated_data["password"]
        instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
```

```
class UserModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = super(UserModelSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        self.create_update_password(instance, validated_data)
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance = super(UserModelSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        self.create_update_password(instance, validated_data)
        return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a decorator to apply the same logic to both methods, so:

```
def create_update_password(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def g(self, *args, **kwargs):
        validated_data = kwargs.get('validated_data') or args[-1]
        result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        result.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        return result
```

and then use this with the [**`@method_decorator`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class):

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(create_update_password, 'create')
@method_decorator(create_update_password, 'update')
class UserModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # …
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions..ill try this